# How to retrieve svn transaction id

Tags: svn, transactions

Is there any possible way for getting the transaction ID in SVN.
I found some svnlook commands having arguments as transaction id 
For Example:

**svnlook author -t xxx /path/to/svn/base**

But no documentation provides how to get that 't'.

Any help would be much appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: when exactly do you want to retreive this ID? in pre-commit hook? You should explain why you want to get this ID.

Comment: Hi Bahrep. I'm trying to enable proxy for svn write(s) to a master via the slave. similar to a kind here [link](https://www.scm-manager.com/2014/04/svn/) . So I want to ensure that the transaction initiated  is carried over to master. 
In pre-commit hook I'm able to get the transaction name, but not transaction id anywhere

Answer (score 2):

The transaction ID is passed to your pre-commit file as an argument.

If you're writing native shell scripts for your pre-commit hooks you can do something like the below at the start of your script.

```
#!/bin/sh

REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"
SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook
```

that would then allow you to go on to do something like.

```
$SVNLOOK author -t $TXN $REPOS
```